# Firefox no reconoce descarga .xls (PHP)

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

Tengo los siguientes `headers` en una vista php

```
header('Content-Type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' .$user[0]. " " .$user[1]. '".xls');
```

con el navegador de `chrome` se descarga el archivo funcionando de manera correcta pero con `firefox` al descargarlo, descarga sin formato, ¿como podria solucionar ese detalle?

Agradeceria el interes.

Comment: ¿Puedes cambiar ese espacio en blanco por un guión?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Firefox estás usando? He probado ese código y me funciona bien en IE, Firefox y Chrome (aunque en algunos añade un carácter raro)

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro estoy usando Firefox Developer Edition pero no me funciona al descargar

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con Mozilla, el Mime correcto es `application/vnd.ms-excel`. Puedes ver la lista 'inCompleta' en [Incomplete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)